# How to connect Dynamodb from Docker?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, amazon-dynamodb

I am running a DynamoDB as docker container on a linux virtual machine.

The url for DnyamoDB docker image: [link](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/dynamodb-local/)

But in the description, no where they mentioned about access key and private key.
If it is aws hosted, we can get that from our account console.
But, how to get create them for local hosted one?
[image: DBeaver image]

I tried connecting with DBeaver and got above settings windows.
Where it is asking for access and secret key.
None of the videos in youtube also I found are explaining about this.

But this is a roadblock to connect to the container.
Please suggest.

Keeping empty and if we test.
[image: error]

Tried other [options](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=340106), but didn't work.

Comment: I have no experience with this image, but from the documentation it looks to me like the keys are not required. What stands out is that you have a typo in the endpoint address, you have a `/` before the colon and the port that doesn't belong there. It should be `http://52.140.69.91:8000`

Comment: Sorry that's a type while taking the screenshot. Now this seems to be working. But the container is not persisting the data once we stop the container and start again. When I check the documentation, it was mentioned in this aws docs about some options but the container is not accepting them. Any suggestions on how to use them. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.UsageNotes.html

Comment: If you were able to solve your connection problem please post your solution (and accept it when you are allowed to) and post your new question separate.

Comment: I gave dummy values instead of empty ones as you suggested, but getting an error when I try to access tables. An unknown operation was requested. (Service: DynamoDb, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 5061edc5-5281-412a-9fdd-c4cc7bd8ac33)
An unknown operation was requested. (Service: DynamoDb, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 5061edc5-5281-412a-9fdd-c4cc7bd8ac33)